# Laravel Session variables in Blade @if

Tags: php, laravel

I've hit some weirdness with Laravel 4.2 when trying to set a JS variable in a blade using Laravel Session to flash some data. It's pretty simply, and I can't figure out what I've missed...

Goal: trigger a Javascript website tour right after a user registers.
Approach: Flash a welcome_tour variable to session, which then sets a JS boolean when the page refreshes which in turn starts the tour in JS.

My register function concludes with the Session setting:

```
Session::flash('welcome_tour', TRUE);
```

And I'm testing that it's picked up and sets the JS variable correctly with the following in my blade:

```
<script>
    @if(Session::has('welcome_tour'))
        var welcome_tour = true;
    @else
        var welcome_tour = false;
    @endif
</script>
{{ var_dump(Session::all()) }}
```

The JS snippet in the resulting HTML indicates that the welcome_tour was not found :-(

```
<script>
    var welcome_tour = false;
</script>
```

But the Session detail printed to the screen by the var_dump indicates that it was set correctly:

```
array (size=4)
  '_token' => string 'HHBowu6wdYlIKy4kFiWYwCe4lQRkFbG7jdNDlYXQ' (length=40)
  'flash' => 
    array (size=2)
      'old' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'welcome_tour' (length=12)
      'new' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  'login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc' => string '1137' (length=4)
  'welcome_tour' => boolean true
```

How can the Session variable be both there and not there??

Comment: What happens if you open the browser console and type `welcome_tour`? Also, is `welcome_tour` in the HTML when you view the page source in your browser?

Comment: Thanks Frank. Bizarrely, the console tells me welcome_tour is correctly set to true. I guess that is enough for me to trigger my tour off of, but it's just weird that the HTML source is setting it to be false and yet it is mysteriously set true somewhere else.

Comment: Do you maybe set the value of `welcome_tour` in multiple places? so you're looking at the wrong part of the HTML source?

Comment: No - a global find only shows `welcome_tour` in this one spot. Just to be 100% convinced, I changed the variable name to be a definately unique `jabba_the_hut` and got exactly the same result -- HTML shows the variable set to false, but the console reports it as true.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use something like that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
if(Session::has('welcome_tour')){
    echo "welcome_tour = true";
}else{
    echo "var welcome_tour = false";
}
?>
</script>
```

and also try `dd(Session::has('welcome_tour'))` to verify the output to condition. might be session has method returning false.

Comment: Thanks Safoor, but how is this different from the code I'm already using? You are using native php `<?php` and `echo` and I'm using blade `@if` and `{{ }}`, but otherwise aren't they identical?

Comment: its just make difference to run condition under if statement.