# Check if session exists inside blade template - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Currently I have the below code in one of my vanilla `php` files

```
<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION['qwick'])) {
    include "checkout-lin.php";
} else {
    include "checkout-nlin.php";
}

?>
```

How can I do the same in laravel. I have created 2 files in my `includes` folder named `loggedinclude.blade.php` and `notloggedinclude.blade` and I now want to add them in a page `checkstatus.blade.php`

Also I'm able to set a session like this

```
$vars = [
    "email" => $email,
    "password" => $password,
    "firstname" => $row['firstName'],
    "lastname" => $row['lastName'],
    "id" => $row['id']
];

session()->put('blog', $vars);
```

From the above code, I'm creating an array then putting the array in a session called blog thereby setting the a session called blog. and now I want to be able to check if a session named blog has been set. blog then has variable email etc

FYI;

my first question is checking for session exist in blade

my second question is checking for named session exist in controller

The documentation only has code for checking `session` items

```
if ($request->session()->has('users')) {
    //
}
```

Comment: as per your code, qwick session is not declared. please add it to $vars. refer my answer for your question as well !

Comment: The first block of code is not in my `blade` file. that is my old code, check the block of the session `blog`

Comment: i see only email, password, firstname, lastname, id session variables

Comment: `qwick` is not a session variable. `qwick` is a session name. Like if I have 3 sections to my site `web`, `blog`, `careers`, a user can sign in to all 3 which means the user has 3 independent sessions

Comment: its my bad. i meant for session name. refer this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649460/laravel-session-variables-in-blade-if

Comment: @moh.ABK they are actually called session variables, not names. that is probably why the confusion with all the comments to all these answers. in php and laravel they are called session variables.

Answer (score 21):

```
@if(session()->has('qwick'))
    @include('includes.loggedinclude')
@else 
    @include('notloggedinclude.loggedinclude')
@endif
```

Documentation about blade can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade).
Session documentation can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session).

Comment: I'm not trying to check for session variables. Rather session name so this does not work

Comment: @moh.ABK what do you mean? this checking the session name

Comment: @AmirBar In `php` you can set multiple sessions with different name. So you can have a session to be set called `guest` when a user decides not to login and also a session called `regular` if a user logs in. these sessions are independent of each other. Example is signing into the `web` section of a site doesn't mean you've signed into the `blog` section.

Comment: yes so guest sessions is: if(session()->has('quest')) and the regular sessions is: if(session()->has('regular'))

Comment: take a look at the has('guest') part you see the "guest" string inside? is like doing in php $_SESSION['guest']

Answer (score 5):

you can use this way for Laravel :
In your Controller or Route function:

```
$request->session()->flash('your_session', 'your message');
```

and in Resource/Views/your_blade_file.blade.php

```
@if (session()->has('your_session'))
    anything ...
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Code Snippet.

```
@if(session->has('qwick')) 
 @include('includes.loggedinclude checkout-lin')
@else
  @include('checkout-nlin')
@endif
```

#### Reference:

[Laravel Session variables in Blade @if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649460/laravel-session-variables-in-blade-if)

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/90/including-a-blade-template-within-another-template

[If statements in blade templating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737961/if-statements-in-blade-templating)

Comment: I'm not trying to check for session variables. Rather session name so this does not work

Comment: you mean $_SESSION['qwick'] is name not variable ?

Comment: I have edited your answer to explain what I want to achieve

Comment: i believe u should update your question not my answer !

Comment: @Venkatraman they are session variables, moh.ABK just wants to call them 'names'.

Answer (score -2):

The better way to check out the user is logged inside the controller. Checking user log in in view section may be break the MVC rule. 
Thanks.

If you must need you can try this

```
@if(session->get('qwick'))
@include("includes.loggedinclude")
@else 
@include("notloggedinclude.loggedinclude")
@endif
```

Comment: What if you want to change the header based on if the user is logged in or not. You will have to put that in the View wouldnt you

Comment: @moh_abk: you can better put this in the controller and push a blade view depending if logged in or not.